# Web Audio API stream audio tags output via http as they are played

Tags: node.js, html, audio, electron, web-audio-api

Im working on an Electron app which takes song/voice requests via a Telegram Bot Api interface and play them in audio objects in a jukebox/radio way.

What i'd like to achieve is live-streaming the audio output of my app via http to the clients who connect to the local (nodejs) server.

So basically i need to process all audio tags PCM as they are played, then mix them (maybe convert the result to mp3 format?) and pipe the result to the clients. At least that's my idea for now.

Unfortunately Im stuck on capturing audio objects outputs.
I read about RecordJs and how it can record audio from an AudioNode Object but i didnt find yet an example of a mixed multiple audio tag outgoing stream.

Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When Web Audio API is rendering the audio is raw PCM (uncompressed) which is available in a memory buffer which gets emptied/reloaded based on buffer allocated size - You can intercept and copy this buffer into a process for downstream publication to clients

save below code as an html file then in same dir serve it using

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

point a browser at http://localhost:8000/
and pick your new html file ... the browser must prompt to ack use of microphone ... then view your javascript console ( ctrl-shift-i ) ... here you see the 1st three elements of FFT and time domain audio array buffers ... in code search on

array_time_domain

which is your raw PCM audio (to be copied and sent to subscribed clients (left as an exercise for the reader ;-))  ... comment out the FFT related code if not needed to lower CPU/battery drain

NOTE - the onaudioprocess callback is called repeatedly as audio is pumped through so assure your above mentioned copy process is very efficient so it completes quicker than the cycle period between audio buffer refreshes (hint Web Worker)

Here I use input source audio coming from the microphone.  This inner callback rendering event loop is the same irrespective of source audio

```
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>capture microphone then show time & frequency domain output</title>

<script type="text/javascript">

var webaudio_tooling_obj = function () {

    var audioContext = new AudioContext();

    console.log("audio is starting up ...");

    var BUFF_SIZE_RENDERER = 16384;
    var SIZE_SHOW = 3; // number of array elements to show in console output

    var audioInput = null,
    microphone_stream = null,
    gain_node = null,
    script_processor_node = null,
    script_processor_analysis_node = null,
    analyser_node = null;

    if (!navigator.getUserMedia)
        navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
    navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia;

    if (navigator.getUserMedia){

        navigator.getUserMedia({audio:true}, 
            function(stream) {
                start_microphone(stream);
            },
            function(e) {
                alert('Error capturing audio.');
            }
            );

    } else { alert('getUserMedia not supported in this browser.'); }

    // ---

    function show_some_data(given_typed_array, num_row_to_display, label) {

        var size_buffer = given_typed_array.length;
        var index = 0;

        console.log("__________ " + label);

        if (label === "time") {

            for (; index < num_row_to_display && index < size_buffer; index += 1) {

                var curr_value_time = (given_typed_array[index] / 128) - 1.0;

                console.log(curr_value_time);
            }

        } else if (label === "frequency") {

            for (; index < num_row_to_display && index < size_buffer; index += 1) {

                console.log(given_typed_array[index]);
            }

        } else {

            throw new Error("ERROR - must pass time or frequency");
        }
    }

    function process_microphone_buffer(event) {

        var i, N, inp, microphone_output_buffer;

        microphone_output_buffer = event.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0); // just mono - 1 channel for now
    }

    function start_microphone(stream){

        gain_node = audioContext.createGain();
        gain_node.connect( audioContext.destination );

        microphone_stream = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
        microphone_stream.connect(gain_node); 

        script_processor_node = audioContext.createScriptProcessor(BUFF_SIZE_RENDERER, 1, 1);
        script_processor_node.onaudioprocess = process_microphone_buffer;

        microphone_stream.connect(script_processor_node);

        // --- enable volume control for output speakers

        document.getElementById('volume').addEventListener('change', function() {

            var curr_volume = this.value;
            gain_node.gain.value = curr_volume;

            console.log("curr_volume ", curr_volume);
        });

        // --- setup FFT

        script_processor_analysis_node = audioContext.createScriptProcessor(2048, 1, 1);
        script_processor_analysis_node.connect(gain_node);

        analyser_node = audioContext.createAnalyser();
        analyser_node.smoothingTimeConstant = 0;
        analyser_node.fftSize = 2048;

        microphone_stream.connect(analyser_node);

        analyser_node.connect(script_processor_analysis_node);

        var buffer_length = analyser_node.frequencyBinCount;

        var array_freq_domain = new Uint8Array(buffer_length);
        var array_time_domain = new Uint8Array(buffer_length);

        console.log("buffer_length " + buffer_length);

        script_processor_analysis_node.onaudioprocess = function() {

            // get the average for the first channel
            analyser_node.getByteFrequencyData(array_freq_domain);
            analyser_node.getByteTimeDomainData(array_time_domain);

            // draw the spectrogram
            if (microphone_stream.playbackState == microphone_stream.PLAYING_STATE) {

                show_some_data(array_freq_domain, SIZE_SHOW, "frequency");
                show_some_data(array_time_domain, SIZE_SHOW, "time"); // store this to record to aggregate buffer/file
            }
        };
    }

}(); //  webaudio_tooling_obj = function()

</script>

</head>
<body>

    <p>Volume</p>
    <input id="volume" type="range" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" value="0.0"/>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: An example would be very useful. Thanks.

Comment: First of all thank you very much for your help. As far as i can see `event.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0)` `inside process_mirophone_buffer` contains some raw data too. What data should i use to build the stream. Sorry but im pretty new to Web Audio Api

Comment: #1 rule of software development --- Shoot First,  ask questions later --- especially when exploring the unknown ... in that spirit to answer your question just comment it out and see what breaks ... nothing ...  the console still dribbles data ... what you speak of is not used and can stay commented out ... array_time_domain has the raw audio you want

Comment: what about the gain node? if i turn down the volume to 0 i still see data coming out of the console while i'd expect to "see" silence in the "graph"

Comment: The html volume UI widget is at the tail end of the data flow and does not control the upstream gain node which acts independently ... good eye ... that volume control is a quick way to squash the forward feedback speaker/mic/speaker squeal

Comment: Any tip on how can i put the gain node in between the source and the analysis processor node so that raw output could be affected by arbitrary volume changes?

Comment: these nodes are lego blocks and so plug N play nicely ... just replace one link in the node chain with two at will ... pluck out current gain node and connect its parent and child nodes directly to see how easily they play together ... then once comfortable define a new gain node wherever you need to

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108447/discussion-between-razorxan-and-scott-stensland).